# How can I explicitly see what 'self' does in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've read somewhere that the use of ‘**self**’ in Python converts `myobject.method (arg1, arg2)` 
into `MyClass.method(myobject, arg1, arg2)`.

Does anyone know how I can prove this? 
Is it only possible if I look at the bytecode by using `dis.dis`?

Comment: The conversion isn't made by python but by `method` object itself which should be a user-defined function object, or otherwise implement appropriate descriptor protocol which returns an object of "instance method" type. This object upon calling indeed performs the substitution you described.

Answer (score 1):

*self* doesn't do anything. *self* is merely the conventional name given to the first argument of a method in Python class definitions. This argument will be passed an instance of the class.

Essentially, to understand what is actually going on, you have to understand Python descriptors. The best places are the official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors) 
To boil it down, descriptor objects are objects that implement `__get__`, `__set__` or `__delete__`. These methods intercept object attribute access, `obj.x`, object attribute assignment: `obj.x = 42`, and object attribute deletion, `del obj.x`.

Also, check out the [HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-howto-guide), where they show how Python [functions and methods are simply descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods), and show an example Python implementation (of course, in CPython, this is implemented in C):

```
class Function(object):
    . . .
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        "Simulate func_descr_get() in Objects/funcobject.c"
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return types.MethodType(self, obj)
```

We can "cheat" and create our own object that merely wraps a function object, and see that this works.

```
import types
class Function:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._func(*args, **kwargs)
    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        "Simulate func_descr_get() in Objects/funcobject.c https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods"
        if obj is None:
            return self
        else:
            return types.MethodType(self, obj)

class Foo:
   def __init__(self):
       self.foo = 42
   bar = Function(lambda self:
       self.foo ** 2
```

And or, in a REPL:

```
>>> import types
>>>
>>> class Function:
...     def __init__(self, func):
...         self._func = func
...     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
...         return self._func(*args, **kwargs)
...     def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
...         "Simulate func_descr_get() in Objects/funcobject.c https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#functions-and-methods"
...         if obj is None:
...             return self
...         else:
...             return types.MethodType(self, obj)
...
>>> class Foo:
...    def __init__(self):
...        self.foo = 42
...    bar = Function(lambda self:
...        self.foo ** 2
...    )
...
>>> Foo().bar()
1764
```

This shows you that the magic behind "self" is merely that function objects *are descriptors*, they implement a `__get__` method which either returns the function itself if called without an instance, or returns a method-object that binds the first argument.

Answer (score 0):

Trying it out for yourself in IDLE could help you out with this:

```
class MyObject(object):
  def method(self, arg1, arg2):
     print(self)

  @staticmethod
  def static_method(arg1, arg2):
     print(arg1)

my_object = MyObject()
my_object.method(1, 2)
>>> <MyObject at 0x1234>
my_object.static_method(1, 2)
>>> 1
```

Python doesn't convert anything, it just silently passes the class instance as the first argument to a class method. Above you can see if you made the method static (via `@staticmethod` decorator), you avoid that extra parameter.