# Keep on getting an AttributeError and not sure why

Tags: python, python-3.x, fractions

```
def gcd(n, d):
        if n==0 or d==0:
            return 1
        while(n != d):
            if(n > d):
                n = n - d
            else:
                d = d - n
        return n

class Fraction:
    def __init__(self, n, d):
        self.num = int(n / gcd(abs(n), abs(d)))
        self.denom = int(d / gcd(abs(n), abs(d)))
        if self.denom < 0:
            self.denom = abs(self.denom)
            self.num = -1 * self.num
        elif self.denom == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError
    def __str__(self):
        if type(self) is tuple:
            if self[1] < 0:
                return '%s/%s' %(self[0], -1*self[1])
            else:
                return '%s/%s' %(self[0], self[1])
        elif self.denom == 1:
            return str(self.num)
        else:
            return '%s/%s' %(self.num, self.denom)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.num*other.denom + self.denom*other.num, self.denom*other.denom

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self.num*other.denom - self.denom*other.num, self.denom*other.denom

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return self.num*other.num, self.denom*other.denom

    def __div__(self, other):
        return self.num*other.denom, self.denom*other.num

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.num == other.num and self.denom == other.denom:
            return "Equal"
        else:
            return "Not Equal"


f1 = Fraction(2, 4)
f2 = Fraction(4, 20)
add = Fraction.__add__(f1, f2)
sub = Fraction.__sub__(f1, f2)
eq = Fraction.__eq__(f1, f2)
mul = Fraction.__mul__(f1, f2)
div = Fraction.__div__(f1, f2)
print("Fraction one: "+str(Fraction.__str__(f1))+"\n"+"Second Fraction: "+str(Fraction.__str__(f2))+"\n"+"Add: "+str(Fraction.__str__(add))+"\n"+"Subtract: "+str(Fraction.__str__(sub))+"\n"+"Multiply: "+str(Fraction.__str__(mul))+"\n"+"Divide: "+str(Fraction.__str__(div))+Fraction.__str__(eq))
```

So my assignment requires me to make a fraction function but I keep on getting the following error for my code and I am not sure why:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Workshops\Week9.py", line 57, in <module>
    print("Fraction one: "+str(Fraction.__str__(f1))+"\n"+"Second Fraction: "+str(Fraction.__str__(f2))+"\n"+"Add: "+str(Fraction.__str__(add))+"\n"+"Subtract: "+str(Fraction.__str__(sub))+"\n"+"Multiply: "+str(Fraction.__str__(mul))+"\n"+"Divide: "+str(Fraction.__str__(div))+Fraction.__str__(eq))
  File "G:\Workshops\Week9.py", line 26, in __str__
    elif self.denom == 1:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'denom'
```

Comment: You're returning a string from `__eq__` (which isn't good), then passing the string `eq` to `str` when you write `Fraction.__str__(eq)`. Why are you manually calling the `__` methods, and why are you returning a string from `__eq__`? Both of those problems are contributing to this error (although the manual calling of the magic methods is the bigger issue).

Comment: I am kind of new to programming but I have been told to show the output and they specifically wanted me to use "__ x __" to define the methods

Comment: @NotHamzah yes, you should define them that way but never call them like that explicitly (outside very peculiar and particular circumstances). So, instead of ` Fraction.__add__(f1, f2)` you should use `f1 + f2` ... that's the *whole point*. Also, why on earth are you checking `if type(self) is tuple:` in your `__str__` implementation? Why would `self` ever be a `tuple`???

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I honestly didn't even know until now that you could just bs what `self` is. I'd never tried. This code messed with my head for a good couple minutes. I'd never seen `self` be anything other than the type of the enclosing class before.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yeah I mean, `SomeClass.func` will always return *just a normal function* which is what methods are. `self` is just a normal parameter, it is merely bound to the instance if called through an instance via the descriptor protocol, because function objects are descriptors! You can define `def foo(self): ...` outside a function, and then assign it to the class `SomeClass.foo = foo` and now it is a method that will work on instances, and again, `self` is merely a *convention* it is only important because it is the *first positional argument*

Comment: I understand that the instance is just always given as the first argument, and that the name `self` is convention, but I'd never tried to call an instance method as though it were a static method before with arguments other than an instance of that class. I thought that'd be an error. Apparently I need to review what's going on behind the scenes here.

Comment: @Carcigenicate they aren't "static methods", they are *just regular old functions*. I wrote [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55114843/5014455) that might be illuminating to another question a while back that shows exactly whats going on behind the scenes... The key is understanding descriptors and the descriptor protocol. EDIT and another answer that might be illuminating: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45645637/5014455

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thanks. I think descriptors touch on some stuff that I've been meaning to look into for awhile now. I'll look over those links after I'm done my current project. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They want you to use `__` to *define* the methods, but that's not how you *use* the methods.

`__add__` for example is `+`. Instead of writing

```
add = Fraction.__add__(f1, f2)
```

Just write

```
add = f1 + f2
```

The same goes for all your other mathematical operators, as well as `__str__` (which is what the `str` built-in uses).

Your main problem is that `eq` is a string*, and you're passing it to your `__str__` method when you write

```
Fraction.__str__(eq)
```

Which means `self` inside of your `__str__` is a *string*, not a *`Fraction`*, which means that `self.denom` is, as the error says, trying to get the `denom` attribute from the string `self`.

Since you have `eq` as a string, just change

```
Fraction.__str__(eq)
```

to just

```
eq
```

---

*Really though, `__eq__` shouldn't be returning a string. It isn't disallowed, but it is bizarre and makes `__eq__` not very useful. Just have

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.num == other.num and self.denom == other.denom
```

Then change the fix above I mentioned to

```
str(eq)
```

Comment: Thanks, it is now working and I managed to get the tuple answer into the form I needed as well.